# Why does Google Firebase Console say I have 5 projects when I can only view 4?

Tags: firebase

[image: When using firebase CLI I type <code>firebase list</code> this is the list of projects.]

[image: This is what Firebase Console displays when I try to start a new project.]

My issue is that when I try to make 5 projects (which is the firebase-spark limit), it won't let me because it thinks I have 5 already. But I only have 4, I think. When I view it on console there's only 4.
Also when I view on the command line it says 4 as well.

Comment: Did you delete any projects recently? Deleted projects are not fully purged until some period (I think ~30 days) after you delete them and count against your project quota until that time.

Comment: Oh, That may be it. I deleted it probably a week ago, but that could make sense thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it takes 2 weeks for projects to update their command line tools, but the good news is they gave me 10 more free projects for submitting a help ticket.

So if you delete a lot of projects and expect to replace them instantly you're gonna have to wait a little while first.